# How do I *completely* disable the Ctrl-O shortcut in Midnight Commander?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, mc

I like using both Midnight Commander and Vim. In Vim, <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> is the "go to previous position" command, and in MC, by default, it toggles between the shell and the panel. I would like to be able to call Vim from MC, and use the <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> from Vim without MC intercepting it and yanking me back to the panel view.

I created a `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` with the following contents:

```
[main]
Shell =
[viewer]
Shell =
[diffviewer]
Shell =
[editor]
Shell =
```

This gets me halfway, in that it disables the shortcut when I call Vim using the <kbd>F4</kbd> key. However, if I run Vim as a shell program, from the input line, and then press <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>, MC still intercepts it.

Is there a configuration option that I'm missing here?

**Note:** I'm reluctant to do any of the following:

- change my default Vim key mappings
- change my preferred editor or file manager
- dig through the MC source code, patch, and recompile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you did not overlook a *configuration setting*.  It is hardcoded in the source file [src/subshell/common.c](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/subshell/common.c#L93), as a variable that "could" be made configurable, but is not:

```
/* The key for switching back to MC from the subshell */
/* *INDENT-OFF* */
static const char subshell_switch_key = XCTRL ('o') & 255;
```

It is only referenced in [one place in the file](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/subshell/common.c#L606): the case which you noticed.

Comment: Patch and recompile it is, then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Still not fixed in 2022. Atrocious.