# configure midnight commander build

Tags: configure

In short: there's no **configure** executable file in mc repo.

Coming from this thread
[How do I *completely* disable the Ctrl-O shortcut in Midnight Commander?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253873/how-do-i-completely-disable-the-ctrl-o-shortcut-in-midnight-commander)

where it became obvious the only way to solve my 'ctrl-o' binding problem is to recompile mc from source because it's hardcoded in source.

So I cloned it

```
git clone https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc.git
```

The install guide says:
start with running **./configure** but I'm stuck because there's no file named **configure** cloned in the repo. (I searched recursively)

Even here they start with ./configure:
https://blog.desdelinux.net/en/mc-con-soporte-samba/

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --enable-vfs-smb --sysconfdir=/etc --mandir=/usr/share/man
```

How? I don't know. That file is missing.
This is what I got in the top level dir of mc repo:

```
.
├── acinclude.m4
├── AUTHORS
├── autogen.sh
├── build-glib2.sh
├── ChangeLog
├── configure.ac
├── contrib
├── COPYING -> doc/COPYING
├── doc
├── INSTALL -> doc/INSTALL
├── lib
├── m4.include
├── maint
├── Makefile.am
├── misc
├── NEWS -> doc/NEWS
├── po
├── README -> doc/README
├── src
├── tests
└── version.sh
```

There's **configure.ac** but it's not executable.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `./autogen.sh` to generate `configure` and a number of other files. This will require a few tools to be installed: `autoconf`, `automake`, `autopoint` and `libtool`.

Once you’ve got `./autogen.sh` to run successfully, you’ll find a `configure` script and you’ll be able to follow the instructions in `INSTALL`.

(The reason those instructions are seemingly incomplete is that they are intended for release tarballs, which include all the files generated by `autogen.sh`. The development repository doesn’t include these files since they are generated.)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, sounds reasonable